# Inline styling with DOM - backgroundColor property not being recognised

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does the button's background not turn blue?

```js
but.style.setProperty('height', '200px');
but.style.setProperty('backgroundColor', 'blue');
```

```html
<button id="but">I am a button</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its `background-color`. [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp#:%7E:text=The%20background%2Dcolor%20property%20sets,the%20text%20easy%20to%20read.)

```js
but.style.setProperty('height', '200px');
but.style.setProperty('background-color', 'blue');
```

```html
<button id="but">I am a button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-color` [css property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp#:%7E:text=The%20background%2Dcolor%20property%20sets,the%20text%20easy%20to%20read.).

```js
but.style.setProperty('height', '200px');
but.style.setProperty('background-color', 'blue');
```

```html
<button id="but">I am a button</button>
```